# How to merge a dataframe with itself by two keys in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this example dataset:

```
   HOME_TEAM      AWAY_TEAM    TIMES
0  Argentina      Uruguay       3
1  Uruguay        Argentina     5
```

And I would like to obtain the times that this teams faced among them.

```
   Matches                TIMES
3  Argentina-Uruguay       8
```

I've been trying the following code:

```
af = af.merge(
    af, 
    left_on=["home_team", "away_team"], 
    right_on=["away_team", "home_team"], 
    how='left'
)
```

the output is:

```
    home_team_x  away_team_y   values_x  home_team_y    away_team_y  values_y
0   Argentina    Uruguay       96        Uruguay        Argentina    80.0
1   Uruguay      Argentina     80        Argentina      Uruguay      96.0
```

Is there a way to do it in a pythonic way and avoiding duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.groupby.sum`:

```
new_df = df["TIMES"].groupby(df.filter(like="TEAM").apply(frozenset, 1)).sum()
new_df.index = ["-".join([t1, t2]) for t1, t2 in new_df.index]
print(new_df.rename_axis("Matches").reset_index())
```

Output:

```
             Matches  TIMES
0  Argentina-Uruguay      8
```

Comment: Is there any link or tutorial to "advance grouping technics", or something like that?
I thought that filters was an alias of "df[ "a filter" ], but I suppose that you could get columns in many ways.

Why did you use frozenset instead of set?


Also, I think in SQL we will have same troubles...

Anyway, this works for me. I'm very glad :-)